# Propane emergency

Tags: propane

My wife and I ran our 500 gallon propane tank out this week and it will be two weeks before we can get another delivery. Can I somehow hook up my house to a portable tank so we can take warm showers ? I don’t run my furnace off of propane just my hot water heater and that’s it, please advise.

Comment: Can you pay for expedited delivery instead?

Comment: What kind of fittings are there between the big tank and the house?

Comment: Yeah, this is a problem with a "wave money around" solution.  Trying to hork-a-dork something together will be more costly still.

Comment: The problem with portable tanks is they freeze up at the high flows normally required by water heaters and furnaces , if you had a larger portable I think 75 or 100 lb can provide the flow you need, and it is simple gas fittings fairly easy to do but most portable tanks freeze up two quickly.